# Using Phonegap with web application for notifications

Tags: php, android, iphone, cordova

I want to create a mobile app for an exisiting website that runs on PHP and MYSQL. Phonegap users, please kindly inform me if it's possible to send mobile notification by interacting with my web application?

Here's an example for better understanding: A web application where users create a list of to do's. User entries are stored in a web database. The objective is to send notifications to their phones via the website server when a "to do" event is due. Can this be achieved with Phonegap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Yes it can. Have you tried much yet?

Notifications while inside the application are a snap - just a regular getJSON poll to some kind of endpoint will work. If you want to use native notifications, that's harder.

Comment: Thanks Danp! I haven't tried Phonegap yet or any other tool kit. It's my first app.